# Find all combination size n from n groups

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I am having a programming problem
Given n-groups of people.
From each group, pick a person to form a new set.
How to find all possible combinations to from a set.

For example: If I have 2 groups
Group 1: Person A, B
Group 2: Person X Y Z

possible sets will be (A,X) (A,Y) (A,Z) (B,X) (B,Y) (B,Z)

Thank you for any help and suggestion.

Bests.

Comment: This is not a programming question... Further, are you looking only for combinations of size 2 ?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem by hand?  If so, try something and edit your question to include a specific problem.  If not, start there first.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the ["product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the n groups. You can implement this recursively:

- for each element in the first group

  - for each product of the remaining groups

    - combine the element with the product and add it to the result

Example-implementation in Python:

```py
def product(lists, pos=0):
    if pos < len(lists):
        for x in lists[pos]:
            for p in product(lists, pos+1):
                yield [x] + p
    else:
        yield []

>>> list(product([[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]))
[[1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], 
 [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 5, 6], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], 
 [3, 4, 6], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 6], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no language constraint is given in the question so I am sharing the code in java. Also the code calculates the cross product of two sets.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Combinations
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        System.out.println(prod(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("A", "B"), Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"))));
    }

    static <String> List<List<String>> prod(List<List<String>> sets) {
    List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    if (sets.size() == 0) {
        res.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        return res;
    } else {
        List<String> set1 = sets.get(0);
        List<List<String>> adLst = prod(sets.subList(1, sets.size()));
        for (String item : set1) {
            for (List<String> lst : adLst) {
                ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                result.add(item);
                result.addAll(lst);
                res.add(result);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

Output

```
[[A, X], [A, Y], [A, Z], [B, X], [B, Y], [B, Z]]
```

Comment: `static <String> ` So, `String` is the name of the type placeholder? Very confusing...

Comment: String(data type in java ) is the just the type of objects the list holds. It can be changed to other data types as well like Integer

Comment: No, it is not. With that first `<String>`, right after `static`, you tell Java, that this is _not_ `java.lang.String`, but a placeholder for _any_ datatype. Don't get me wrong, using a generic data type is a good idea for this method, but you should definitely _not_ call that generic data type `<String>`. Instead, use `<T>` or something like that, and then `List<T>` etc.